# go-sqlcipher: failed to compile/run sample on Windows

Tags: go, go-sqlite3

I'm using **Windows** Server 2019 x64. Trying to leverage **go-sqlcipher** to manipulate sqlite database.

But it always **fails** when I try to run the [sample](https://github.com/xeodou/go-sqlcipher/blob/master/_example/encrypto/encrypto.go).

```
# go run .\encrypto.go
# github.com/xeodou/go-sqlcipher
sqlite3-binding.c:24328:26: fatal error: openssl/rand.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Did you install the driver "github.com/xeodou/go-sqlcipher"?

Comment: Hi @PratheeshM Do you mean go-sqlite3? If so: Yes.

Comment: I tried to install "github.com/xeodou/go-sqlcipher", it pops the same error

Answer (score 0):

After searching around, still no way to solve it.

Until I changed to another repository

- https://github.com/mutecomm/go-sqlcipher

```html
> go run .\main.go
{"name":"jason", "password": "1234"}{"name":"xeodou", "password": "123456"}
```